# Firebase email authentication not redirecting if url contains #?

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase email authentication but I can't seem to get firebase to redirect to correct url after clicking the link in email:

Basically the code is this:

```
let actionCodeSettings = {
    url: "http://localhost:8005/#/auth",
    handleCodeInApp: true,
}

await sendSignInLinkToEmail(auth, email, actionCodeSettings);

// Then you click on the link you receive in the email
// You get redirected to http://localhost:8005/?apiKey=<api_key_is_here>
```

I've tried with different types of urls such as:

```
"http://localhost:8005/auth" // this works fine
```

Am I doing something wrong or do I have to create a work-around for this such as checking query parameters if they contain a certain keyword? I need the # in the url because I'm using hash based routing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a comment in a readme.md

https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/blob/master/README.md

```
          // So for a url: https://www.example.com/#/signin
          // The completion URL will take the form:
          // https://www.example.com/?uid_sid=xyz&ui_sd=0#/signin
          // This should be taken into account when using frameworks with "hash
          // routing".
```

So you have to work around this. I abandoned the hash based routing because of this and use subdomains instead.